# One to Many, select one and many in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have four tables

POST -- USER --IMAGE-- COMMENT

I want to retrieve the information about all the posts, the users who posted them, the image associated with it (each post has only one image) and the (list/array) comments associated with every given post.

This is what I have :

```
SELECT * 
FROM post 
LEFT JOIN image 
    ON post.image_id=image.id 
LEFT JOIN user 
    ON user.id=post.user_id 
LEFT JOIN comment 
    ON comment.post_id =post.id
```

This almost works, except that each post record is is repeated for each of its many comments. How do I get one record with all the comments in it ?

Comment: You'll want to use Group_concat but it's tough to give you an example without knowing the field names

Comment: Just live with the repeats. They're fine.

Comment: Just to clarify...you currently have a select statement where it is returning several comments for one post, and instead of having each post/comment being it's own row, you'd prefer to have this as one line as post and then an array of comments?  If so...why?

Comment: It's worse than you think. It will be repeated for each distinct combination of related image, user, and comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except that the `*` operator is really inefficient, you just can't do in only one query "one post"<=>"many comment". Every entry will merge the post and its comment.

You can use a trick, like `GROUP_CONCAT` to create a "row of comments". But it will be really weird.

An example for `Group_Concat`

```
SELECT p.*, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(image.url SEPARATOR "~") AS image_url, GROUP_CONCAT(comment.text SEPARATOR "#~#") AS comment_text
   FROM post p 
LEFT JOIN image 
    ON p.image_id=image.id 
LEFT JOIN user 
    ON user.id=p.user_id 
LEFT JOIN comment 
   ON comment.post_id =p.id
```

it will give you one line per post with each comment glued one to another by a "#~#". Not so cool.

I think you just have to let it be like SQL handles it naturally.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for more than one query. You could select the images, then for each one select the comments, or you could select the images, then select all comments and group them as necessary in code. The choice between those depends on how you're using it. But if you want to adhere to relational database design patterns, you'll want to do this as more than one query. You can't return an array like you're looking for.